Api authentication with sanctum not working in laravel-11
I am using Sanctum in my laravel 11 application. Able to create token in login. But api is not able to authenticate using the generated token. No error showing. The server stops with showing any error.
config/auth.php
   'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'members',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'members',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'members' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Member::class,
    ],
],

Kernel.php
 protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
];



protected $middlewareGroups = [
    
    'api' => [
      \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
       'throttle:api',
       \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.dap' => \App\Http\Middleware\DapAuthentication::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
    'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
    'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
    'has_business_access' => \App\Http\Middleware\HasBusinessAccess::class,
    'create-link.verify' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCreateLink::class,
    'chilli-token.verify' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyChilliToken::class,
    'twilio-callback.verify' => \App\Http\Middleware\TwilioRequestValidator::class,
    'whatsapp-callback.verify' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateWhatsAppWebhook::class,
    'XSS' => \App\Http\Middleware\XSS::class
];

api.php
        Route::get('/profile', [AuthController::class, 'profile'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

The route works with out middleware('auth:sanctum')
